# Parsing HTML to retrieve embedded data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shell, wifi

I want to know if it is possible to parse a table of data in a browser supported language. Specifically I'm trying to parse WPA_CLI data, such as below, after it is handed to the browser (i.e. the data is hidden in a HTML paragraph or something of that nature).

```
Selected interface 'mlan0'
OK
Selected interface 'mlan0'
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
c8:3a:35:3d:d3:20   2412    203 [WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP]    network1
08:ea:44:98:7c:95   2412    195 [WPA-EAP-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-EAP-TKIP+CCMP] test
08:ea:44:98:7c:96   2412    195 [WPA-EAP-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-EAP-TKIP+CCMP] 
08:ea:44:98:7c:d5   2437    181 [WPA-EAP-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-EAP-TKIP+CCMP] test
20:4e:7f:89:9c:e4   2417    177 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP] My Router
00:17:47:60:71:df   2412    171 [WPA-PSK-TKIP]  AP with Spaces
12:18:0a:10:0e:80   2462    200 [WEP]       WEP Networks Have
16:18:0a:10:0e:80   2462    199 [WEP]       Two Tabs before this WTF
02:2d:fd:d9:08:09   2442    179 [WEP][IBSS]     Another Network
00:18:0a:10:0e:80   2462    198         Test Network
26:18:0a:10:12:76   2447    168
```

To be specific wpa_cli generates this table from a shell command (which also generates my html/javascript/etc.), however I want to avoid server side parsing/processing because my embedded device doesn't have the resources to spare.

For example I want to skip the first 4 lines. Then go 3 tabs, if the first five letters are [WPA2 or [WPA- then go another tab and get the last string on the line and put it in a variable, etc. As you can see the data is not well organized; a WEP network has two tabs after WEP instead of all the other networks which only have one.

If it is possible, what is the best technique to parse data like this while keeping it out of server side scripting?

Comment: Still could really use some help with this. I'm not looking for the code handed to me, just some idea's if it's possible to do and how I might get started if it is??

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript I am able to split the data into lines first using something like this:

```
theDataBlock.split('\n');
```

Then I can split each of those line arrays by tabs, giving me individual data sets of 4 or 5. From there it's all standard use of control structures to manipulate the data.